# Reasons for stuck AppDomain Unload

Tags: .net, azure, appdomain, azure-web-app-service, domainunload

I am still trying to understand ongoing problem, but it can pretty much be summarized as ***inability to unload AppDomain***.

It happens during the deployment of ASP.NET WebAPI to Azure App Service and what we observe is the following:

1. **Process ID does not change**, new deployment is hosted within very same process (AFAIU it's done via unload of old AppDomain and spinning up a new AppDomain with updated binaries)
2. Azure PaaS diagnostics shows the following in the errors section:

> "In w3wp_12396.dmp, the HttpRuntime for the application
>   /LM/W3SVC/1523308129/ROOT is **in the middle of a shutdown**."

2. Analyzing memory dumps we see Threads with **IsAbortRequested** flag set, but they never seem to finish (output of WinDbg `!threads` here: https://pastebin.com/7CXYcffy)
3. In memory dumps we also see a lot of AppDomains with "**UNLOAD_REQUESTED**" stage, they never seem to finish unloading (full output of `!DumpDomain` is here: https://pastebin.com/kahZQuWN)

```
Domain 7:           000001c67062c800
LowFrequencyHeap:   000001c67062cff8
HighFrequencyHeap:  000001c67062d088
StubHeap:           000001c67062d118
Stage:              UNLOAD_REQUESTED
SecurityDescriptor: 000001c6705c5680
Name:               /LM/W3SVC/1523308129/ROOT-6-131687140950004974
```

4. **No deadlocks** detected (via WinDbg SOSEX plugin's `!dlk` command  at least, which usually covers majority of deadlock cases)
5. **No code cancels Thread Abort** (no `Thread.ResetAbort()` called)

The only way we can fix the problem now is to kill process (stop Azure AppService).

What are the **possible reasons** for AppDomain's inability to unload?

**UPDATE**. In the thread stacks we got a hint that it might have something to do with our custom Azure Blob Log4net appender, and I found that when such appender is created (once per app) it spawns new thread with following structure.

```
while (true)
{
   try
   {
        Flush(); // pseudocode
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
   }
}
```

Not sure I understand why it can cause totally unstoppable threads (because `ThreadAbortException` will not be stopped by catch), but it looks like changing `while (true)` to `while (!Environment.HasShutdownStarted && !_stopping)` solves the issue (`_stopping` is set when Appender `OnClose` is called which is kind of graceful shutdown for log4net)...

Comment: AppDomain.Unload is pretty tricky, the CLR has to perform a "rude abort" on any threads that are still executing code in that domain.  It is not actually that rude, the thread has to be in a safe place so that killing it can come to a good end.  First problem you have is that there are still thread(s) executing code in that domain, not at all a happy case.  Next problem you have is that you don't know what those thread(s) are doing, implicit from not knowing what they are working on.  Only an unmanaged debugger can show you the troublesome stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant, appreciate you, such a famous person in SO world, providing your input on that. Please check out the answer I've just added. The problem seems to be caused by nasty JIT bug that can easily be reproduced via small code snippet in answer below.

Comment: You are just seeing what the CLR has to do to perform an abort on a thread that is not making it easy .  It tries repeatedly, hoping that it eventually hits it when it is either executes managed code or calls an alertable OS function.  An alertable OS function is one that allows QueueUserApc() to execute.  Like SleepEx().  The CLR tries very hard to provide that guarantee.  But it is not like, say, anti-malware being anti can't give it a hard time.  You can only see such an OS function back with an unmanaged debugger.

Comment: @HansPassant, that makes sense, thanks for deep explanatory references! But come on, did you expect that `ThreadAbortException` that is [claimed by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to be automatically rethrown is not rethrown? :)

Comment: A rude abort does not use TAE.  Ask a team member that is less afraid of rudeness and unmanaged debugging to help you out.

Comment: @HansPassant, any references for "app domain unload is not using TAE"? WinDbg seems to disagree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a JIT bug. Yes, **BUG IN JIT**! I found almost the same story documented there: http://labs.criteo.com/2017/04/ryujit-never-ending-threadabortexception/.

To demonstrate the issue you can run the following code. Only works in Release mode, only for x64 platform (and I'm targeting .NET 4.5.2).

You will observe endless chain of the exceptions logged unless you manually rethrow the exception. Why it's the bug in CLR/JIT? Because CLR/JIT is responsible for injecting throw `ThreadAbortException` in a "safe places" when thread's AbortRequested flag is set.

Quote by Jeffrey Richter from "CLR via C#" (violated for the code below):

> Even when code catches the `ThreadAbortException`, the CLR doesn’t allow
>   the exception to be swallowed. In other words, at the end of the catch
>   block, the CLR automatically rethrows the `ThreadAbortException`
>   exception.

Also the bug in GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/16122.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mutex = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!mutex.IsSet)
                {
                    mutex.Set();
                }

                // Do some stuff

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);

                // the lines below FIX the issue
                //if (ex is ThreadAbortException)
                //    throw;
            }

            // FIXES the issue as well
            //Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    });

    t.Start();

    // Wait for the thread to start
    mutex.Wait();

    t.Abort();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```